# HTML5 Offline App files using the Cache Manifest is never updated

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, browser-cache

I have developed a HTML5 mobile app with jQueryMobile and I'm trying to provide the offline feature for allowing the users to use the app without Internet connectivity.
I have been following this tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

- The Manifest file was created.
- The mime-type text/cache-manifest was added to the .htaccess file.
- Pages contain the manifest file in the HTML tag.

I test it and it seems to work. When I'm without connection, the web navigation between my pages still works.
Nevertheless, I'm detecting two main issues:

1) Offline navigation works when I get in the app with connectivity and then I switch it off. When opening the app from the mobile device browser writting the URL whitin the address bar without connectivity, the web app is not loaded!! Although I visited the web app before.

2) Web app files are never updated. For instance:

- I change something in the catched CSS file.
- I update a comment in the Manifest file to tell the app to update its
  files.
- The CSS file is never updated. The current version is the previous
  one.

I try to detect the Cache's Status from JavaScript for managing the page refresh:

```
function checkCacheVersion(){
    var webappCache = window.applicationCache;
    if(webappCache){
        //0-> unchached
        //1-> idle
        //2-> checking
        //3-> downloading
        //4-> updateready
        console.log('Cache state= ' +  webappCache.status);
        if(webappCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY){
            console.log('[Cache] There is an update waiting for reload');
            webappCache.swapCache();
            location.reload();
        }
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, the Cache Status is always "Idle" status. What does it means?
I understand, I would receive the "Uncached" status if the Cache wasn't configured properly. Right?

On the other hand, the example's CSS file is only refreshed if I remove it from the Manifest file. So the browser detects the file is not catched and obtains it correctly (I mean, Cache is properly configured, right?).

Could you please help me to find out where the problem is?
Many thanks!!

Sergi

Comment: I've also noticed that detecting an updated cache manifest doesn't work well. Maybe the HTTP Expires header causes the problem?

Comment: Yes, it seems the cache header has a 7 days max-age. How can it be edited?